# Showing categories in structure navigation

Tags: structure

I have a site that has a parent channel as a main nav item. It has entries that are categorized.

Is it possible to have the parent channel in the main nav and it's categories as children using structure?

Answer (score 0):

Structure and categories work best when used with Zoo Triggers. for what i know, ZT has been aquired by eeharbor, and they are currently working ZT into Structure.What i normally do for the nav is something like

```
{if segment_1 == 'parent_channel'}
    {exp:channel:categories}<li><a href="/{segment_1}/{category_name}">{category_name}</a></li>
{if:else}
    {exp:structure:nav}
{/if}
```

I normally also set Freebie to have EE ignore all segments after my parent_channel, so i don't need a category trigger word.
In my Structure template i normally use Switchee to display the correct entries